# C++ Statement Reordering

Tags: c++, optimization, memory, time, compiler-construction

This is a question about Chandler's answer here (I didn't have a high enough rep to comment): [Enforcing statement order in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786547/enforcing-statement-order-in-c/)

In his answer, suppose foo() has no input or output.  It's a black box that does work that is observable eventually, but won't be needed immediately (e.g. executes some callback).  So we don't have input/output data locally handy to tell the compiler not to optimize.  But I know that foo() will modify the memory somewhere, and the result will be observable eventually. Will the following prevent statement reordering and get the correct timing in this case?

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

//I believe this tells the compiler that all memory everywhere will be clobbered?
//(from his cppcon talk: https://youtu.be/nXaxk27zwlk?t=2441)
__attribute__((always_inline)) inline void DoNotOptimize() {
  asm volatile("" : : : "memory");
}

// The compiler has full knowledge of the implementation.
static int ugly_global = 1; //we print this to screen sometime later
static void foo(void) { ugly_global *= 2; }

auto time_foo() {
  using Clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

  auto t1 = Clock::now();         // Statement 1
  DoNotOptimize();
  foo();                          // Statement 2
  DoNotOptimize();
  auto t2 = Clock::now();         // Statement 3

  return t2 - t1;
}
```

Comment: Don't you want [std::memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) rather than compiler specific hacks?

Comment: Writes to memory _are_ side effects, so if `foo` modifies memory somewhere, then the compiler can't reorder the clock calls.  Otherwise it would be impossible to write programs and have them do what you wanted.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't know how I would use std::memory_order here ... I'm not working with specific locations in memory (known outside the black box). Maybe I'm just unfamiliar with them though.

Comment: @P.Mattione To be honest, I don't know either. It was just the first thing that sprung into my mind when I saw your question. So I may well be completely off topic / wrong.

Comment: @MooingDuck To make sure I understand ... suppose the DoNotOptimize() call was not there.  I would think the compiler could swap Statement 1 & 2 because there would be no observable difference in their order, right?  Because the compiler can't reason about how long something takes.  But you're saying it should work because of the DoNotOptimize() call?

Comment: @MooingDuck: That feels wrong to me! If there is no dependency between the calls of `foo()`  and `Clock::now()`, the compiler is able to reorder execution. It might be that `Clock::now()` forces the compiler to not reorder, but is this really the case, especially is it guaranteed on all platforms? Maybe also the CPU may execute assembly instructions in different order if not explicit vorbidden...

Comment: My point is that `foo` writes to memory not on the call stack.  This is a side effect (for the purposes of reordering) That means everything before those writes must remain before, and everything after those writes must remain after. The compiler can't move either clock call.  DoNotOptimize() is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That something writes data did not mean that is a dependency! If two functions manipulate unrelated data, everything can mixed until some other part of the code needs the results of that code.

Comment: I checked, you're right. The compiler may re-order reads and writes to memory when it can prove that such re-ordering won’t affect program behaviour (but timing doesn't count as behavior). So you do indeed need a `std::memory_order` here

Comment: @MooingDuck: Please add me with a@ to your comment to get notified :-) And as mentioned: The hardware itself can reorder execution which is out of control of the compiler as long no special instructions are emitted which stop these reordering! See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27471969/compiler-reordering-vs-memory-reordering. Also memory_order did not prevent anything, as time consuming things which have no side effects can be reordered

Comment: @Klaus: the compiler can only reorder the calls to `Clock::now()` and `foo()` if it knows there are no dependencies between them.  In the absesnce of inforamtion about their internals it must assume they depend.  Similarly, the hardware can only reorder instructions it knows are not dependent.  One would expect the implementation of `Clock::now()` contains a barrier instruction os some kind, as it is otherwise useless.

Comment: @ChrisDodd "as it is otherwise useless." But this is nowhere defined in the standards as I can see. Maybe I did not read careful enough...

Comment: @Klaus: technically, yes, the standard does not specify anything about the accuracy of clocks, so times may off by years and still be (technically) standards-compliant, but any such implemention would probably be considered poor.  In general, one would assume they give reasonably reliable times.

Answer (score 1):

> Will the following prevent statement reordering and get the correct timing in this case?

It should not be necessary because the calls to `Clock::now` should, at the language-definition level, enforce enough ordering.  (That is, the C++11 standard says that the high resolution clock ought to get as much information as the system can give here, in the way that is most useful here.  See "secondary question" below.)

But there is a more general case.  It's worth thinking about the question: *How does whoever provides the C++ library implementation actually write this function?*  Or, take C++ itself out of the equation.  Given a language standard, how does an implementor—a person or group writing an implementation of that language—get you what you need?  Fundamentally, we need to make a distinction between *what the language standard requires* and *how an implementation provider goes about implementing the requirements*.

The language itself may be expressed in terms of an *abstract machine*, and the C and C++ languages are.  This abstract machine is pretty loosely defined: it executes some kind of instructions, which access data, but in many cases we don't know *how* it does these things, or even how big the various data items are (with some exceptions for fixed-size integers like `int64_t`), and os on.  The machine may or may not have "registers" that hold things in ways that cannot be addressed as well as memory that *can* be addressed and whose addresses can be recorded in pointers:

```
p = &var
```

makes the value store in `p` (in memory or a register) such that using `*p` accesses the value stored in `var` (in memory or a register—some machines, especially back in the olden days, have / had addressable registers).<sup>1</sup>

Nonetheless, despite all of this abstraction, we want to run real code on real machines.  Real machines have real constraints: some instructions might require particular values in particular registers (think about all the bizarre stuff in the x86 instruction sets, or wide-result integer multipliers and dividers that use special-purpose registers, as on some MIPS processors), or cause CPU sychronizations, or whatever.

GCC in particular invented a system of constraints to express what you could or could not do on the machine itself, using the machine's instruction set.  Over time, this evolved into user-accessible `asm` constructs with input, output, and clobber sections.  The particular one you show:

> ```
> __attribute__((always_inline)) inline void DoNotOptimize() {
>   asm volatile("" : : : "memory");
> }
> ```

expresses the idea that "this instruction" (`asm`; the actual provided instruction is blank) "cannot be moved" (`volatile`) "and clobbers all of the computer's memory, but no registers" (`"memory"` as the clobber section).

This is not part of either C or C++ as a *language*.  It's just a *compiler construction*, supported by GCC and now supported by clang as well.  But it suffices to force the compiler to issue all stores-to-memory before the `asm`, and reload values from memory as needed after the `asm`, in case they changed when the computer executed the (nonexistent) instruction included *in* the `asm` line.  There's no guarantee that this will work, or even compile at all, in some *other* compiler, but as long as we're the *implementor*, *we* choose the compiler we're implementing for/with.

C++ as a language now has support for ordered memory operations, which an implementor must implement.  The implementor can use these `asm volatile` constructs to achieve the right result, provided they do actually achieve the right result.  For instance, if we need to cause the machine itself to synchronize—to emit a memory barrier—we can stick the appropriate machine instruction, such as `mfence` or `membar #sync` or whatever it may be, in the `asm`'s instruction-section clause.  See also [compiler reordering vs memory reordering](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27471969/1256452) as [Klaus mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232047/c-statement-reordering#comment106539899_60232047).

It is up to the implementor to find an appropriately effective trick, compiler-specific or not, to get the right semantics while minimizing any runtime slowdown: for instance, we might want to use `lfence` rather than `mfence` if that's sufficient, or `membar #LoadLoad`, or whatever the right thing is for the machine.  If our implementation of `Clock::now` requires some sort of fancy inline `asm`, we write one.  If not, we don't.  We make sure that we produce what's required—and then all *users* of the system can just use it, without needing to know what sort of grubby implementation tricks we had to invoke.

There's a secondary question here: does the language specification *really* constrain the implementor the way we think/hope it does?  [Chris Dodd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60232047/c-statement-reordering#comment106543710_60232047) says he thinks so, and he's usually right on these kinds of questions.  A couple of other commenters think otherwise, but I'm with Chris Dodd on this one.  I think it is not necessary.  You can always compile to assembly, or disassemble the compiled program, to check, though!

If the compiler *didn't* do the right thing, that `asm` would force it to do the right thing, in GCC and clang.  It probably wouldn't work in other compilers.

---

<sup>1</sup>On the KA-10 in particular, the registers were just the first sixteen words of memory.  As [the Wikipedia page notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-10#Registers), this meant you could put instructions into there and call them.  Because the first 16 words were the registers, these instructions ran much faster than other instructions.